# Scraping product data from site using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Why is my code not working? I've tried many times but still facing an error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

```
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json
import pandas as pd
base = 'https://mamaearth.in/product/{}'
link = 'https://mmrth-nd-api.honasa-production.net/v1/products/shopAllProducts'
params = {
    'pagenumber': 1,
    'pagesize': '20',
    'categoryId': '-1'
}
headers = {
    'Referer': 'https://mamaearth.in/',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    while True:
        res = s.get(link,params=params)
        try:
            container = res.json()['response']['list']['entities']['products']
        except KeyError:
            break
        hreff=[]    
        for val in container.values():
            hreff.append(base.format(val['slug']))
        params['pagenumber']+=1
        Prod_list=[]
        for i in hreff:
            r = requests.get(i, headers=headers)
            soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
            pro_name=soup.find('h1',class_='ProductDetailsRevamp__ProdName-sc-1w9tx2u-1 dTITDo').text.strip()
            price=soup.find('td', class_='price').text.strip()
            Prod = {
                'Pro_Name':pro_name,
                'Price':price,
                'Product_link':link,
                }
            Prod_list.append(Prod)
            df=df=pd.DataFrame(Prod_list)
        print(df)
    df.to_csv('Output.csv', index = False)
```

Whenever I run this code to scrape the product name and price from the product page (or product link I get through my code only), I face an error.
[image: Error image uploaded]
Error says that "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'" but at the same time it is also giving the output for some products like half of them.

Comment: In order to answer your question we need a little more info than this. At a bare minimum, it'd be useful to know where your program fails

Comment: @MiguelGuthridge I've edited my question for better understanding. Please go through that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your call to `soup.find('h1',class_='ProductDetailsRevamp__ProdName-sc-1w9tx2u-1 dTITDo')` fails to find any results, and therefore returns `None`. You should check whether it is None before trying to extract any information from it.

```py
item=soup.find('h1',class_='ProductDetailsRevamp__ProdName-sc-1w9tx2u-1 dTITDo')
if item is None:
    # We didn't find anything, skip over this item
    print(f"No match found for {i}")
    continue
    
pro_name = item.text.strip()
```